# Await for Complete Status of GetQueryResults using NodeJs/Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

am trying to get results from Cloudwatchlogs using GetQueryResults through a Lambda using nodejs, but cant figure out how to wait till the status reaches complete. Dont want to use SetTimeout. Is there a graceful way to achieve this other than SetTimeout? Any help is appreciated.

```
exports.handler = async (event) =>  {
        RequestIDPromise = cloudwatchlogs.startQuery(CWparams).promise()
        
        return RequestIDPromise.then((response)=>
        {
            GetQueryParamPromise = cloudwatchlogs.getQueryResults(response).promise();

            return GetQueryParamPromise.then((data)=>
            {
                console.log(data.results[]) // Shows up as empty
                console.log(data.status) // Shows up as running.

                //do some activity with the Query results but it shows up empty as its in running state
                // .....
```

Comment: Code is incomplete

Comment: Hi @sudo_kaizen, I have mentioned the block where I am facing an issue. The rest of it is to add the results to a SNS payload and publish them to a SNS topic.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question Lawrence Cherone.